Owner of Active Directory object is changed
When owner of Active Directory object is changed, eventid 5136 is not  triggered even though it has proper audit policy enabled and object level auditing. Instead eventid 4662 is generated
There is no WRITE_OWNER for active directory objects.Tried with Full control. still event 5136 is not triggered with owner changes

Object level auditing for which type of access? Auditing WRITE attempts probably won't do, I expect you need to specifically audit WRITE_OWNER

There is no WRITE_OWNER for active directory objects.Tried with Full control. still event 5136 is not triggered with owner changes

It may be a better idea to track "Write_Owner" Access Type in "Access Field" of the event for this case as outlined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4662#security-monitoring-recommendations.   "Access Mask : 0x80000 WRITE_OWNER The right to assume ownership of the object"

@ErkinD39 , I am able to track 4662 event when owner get changed , My question is that will it trigger 5136 event when owner is changed ?

I do no think so, it seems that ownership change is treated differently from writing an attribute. "To generate this event, the modified object must have an appropriate entry in SACL: the “Write” action auditing for specific attributes." Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5136
